# bash: homestead: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, laravel, fedora, homestead

I install homestead and laravel but when i write the command in command line there is error the command not found for both laravel and homestead so i search a lot and i found that i must add the path so i added in efferent way but still the same error command not found.
and this is my bash profile is there any wrong when i added the path?

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export composer=php /usr/bin/composer.phar
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin/:$PATH:/home/alsachit/.composer
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `export composer=php /usr/bin/composer.phar` -- did you mean `alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer.phar'`

Comment: i do a lot of thing but all not working i remove this edit but still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run Laravel commands from Laravel project directory, like `php artisan` or `composer`. If you will run there commands from other directories, you can meet a lot of errors (a lot of guys ask for help on SO because of it), so my advice is to keep it simple.

UPDATE:

```
COMPOSER_PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin
PATH=$COMPOSER_PATH:$PATH
export PATH
```

Another way which may work for you:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Comment: the command laravel is not found so how can i create project to run the command from the project directory and also homestead command not working

Comment: Try to do it like this. Go to directory where you want to place your Laravel project with `cd` command. Then run this `/path_to_composer/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel name_of_laravel_app`

Comment: yes its work in this way but why didn't work when i added a path like other people in the world :)

Comment: Well, setting `PATH` is just an alternative. I don't use it just for all apps, just for Git and few others. I did not use Fedora for years, but I found code for Laravel 4 which you can try (look at updated post). Also, reboot after editing `/.bashrc`, just for case.

Comment: yes its working thanks a lot but i think it just work globally right?

Comment: Yep, it should work globally. I'm glad I could help. )

Answer (score 1):

I believe to directly answer the issue `homestead: command not found`
you must perform steps below:

1. Add bash function into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file:

```
# Homestead shortcut
function homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

2. Restart terminal, see image below for possible output.

[image: After restart terminal]