# "homestead command not found" even after Installing laravel homestead in Linux mint 18

Tags: linux, bash, laravel, homestead

I am trying to install laravel homestead in linux mint 18. I have installed vagrant and virtual box from follwing URLs successfully:

> https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
>
> https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

I have installed homestead with following command

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

i have installed composer successfully. when i give composer command in terminal it shows me composer options so it is working correctly. 
i have also set the PATH file with:

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

If i run echo $PATH it gives me following output:

> /home/ahnaf/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

if i run homestead it gives me.

> homestead command not found.

but if i restart the terminal and run echo $PATH then the composer path is not there any more. I have browsed through laravel docs , laracasts and in google.Everywhere i found the solution supposed to be to set the PATH which i did, but my problem is still present. dnt know what to do. is there any linux user who can help me to set the homestead?

Comment: Did you do a re-source of your profile? `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: no. should i do it after running export path ?? and i have bashrc in my home folder. should i run bashrc or profile ?

Comment: Sorry - to access the `homestead` command globally you should check the official docs - https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#accessing-homestead-globally. The command `source ~/.profile` is only needed if you did not restart your terminal, which you did.

Comment: how to make sure my homestead installation is working right or not

Comment: To make sure your homestead installation is working correctly I suggest using the official docs - https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead - step by step. Homestead is just a virtual machine. Please see the vagrant commands how to control virtual machines.

Comment: if i install something with composer global then where the files should be in my filesystem in linux. i know it should be ~/.composer/vendor/bin folder in mac . but my linux root does not have any ~/.composer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: homestead: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683924/bash-homestead-command-not-found)